# how to make a function available at start up in R

Tags: r, function

I have a user defined function in R

```
blah=function(a,b){
something with a and b
}
```

is it possile to put this somewhere so that I do not need to remember to load in the workspace every time I start up R? Similar to a built in function like

```
summary(); t.test(); max(); sd()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the function into your [`.rprofile` file](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html).

However, be *very* careful with what you put there, since it essentially makes your code non-reproducible — it now depends on your `.rprofile`:

Let’s say you have an R code file performing some analysis, and the code uses the function `blah`. Executing the code on any other system will fail due to the non-existence of the `blah` function.

As a consequence, this file should only contain system-specific setup. Don’t define helper functions in there — or if you do, make them defined only in interactive sessions, so that you have a clear environment when R is running a non-interactive script:

```
if (interactive()) {
    # Helper functions go here.
}
```

And if you find yourself using the same helper functions over and over again, bundle them into packages (or [modules](https://github.com/klmr/modules)) and reuse those.

Comment: That is a great explanation. As the functions will only be used by me, I might modify them into my .rprofile as you suggest, but I will use the function repeatedly, so will look into making modules... next step in learning R :)