# How to put quotes around several words quickly in Rstudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

How to I make MI, ID, FL, into "MI", "ID", "FL" without having to type every single double quote?

Comment: I think your question has been missunderstood. You mean doing it in the editor. I agree it could be a good addition, you could ask for a addin or directly to rstudio to link that feature to some key shortcut.

Comment: We still don't have this feature implemented nor any addin doing it.

Comment: I've open an feature request here, https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/1628   I don't know if they will take it into consideration.  You can upvote there.

Answer (score 10):

The Hmisc package has a function Cs(), it will evaluate comma separated text as having quotes.

```
Cs(MI, ID, FL)
#becomes:
"MI", "ID", "FL"
```

Answer (score 10):

You may want to check out the **[datapasta](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html)** package!

If you follow directions under **"Pasting a list as a horizontal vector with vector_paste()"** of the linked vignette, you'll be able to type something like `MI, ID, FL` cut it and then use an assigned keyboard shortcut, say `shift + cmd + v`, to paste it into `c("MI", "ID", "FL")`.

Comment: This option does not seem to exsit any more in the `datapasta` add-in

Answer (score 6):

Use the following steps in RStudio:

1. Select the text that you want each word quoted for.
2. Open find/replace (<kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd>)
3. Check the "In selection" box
4. Type comma space into the find field: [, ]
5. Type quote comma space quote into the replace field: [", "]
6. Select the **All** button after the replace field
7. Type the initial and final quotation marks.

I use this procedure frequently. I hope someone will write an RStudio addin that provides a keyboard shortcut!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that I frequently use to quickly convert a string of variables separated by commas to a double-quoted string separated by commas directly from the clipboard after you've copied some the text.  This method works great too if your original text is in another program or editor window on your computer:

Define the following function in your R Code and *immediately run* it:

```
quote_strings <- function() {
  quoted_string <- readClipboard() %>%
    str_split_1(",") %>%
    {
      glue_collapse(glue('"{str_trim(.)}"'), sep = ", ")
    }
  (rstudioapi::insertText(paste("#", quoted_string, "\n")))
  return(quoted_string)
}
```

Now paste the following code in your source editor:

```
quoted_string<-quote_strings()
```

Now copy and paste a comma-separated value list from somewhere on your computer.  It should be formed just as you specified (e.g. XXXXX, YYY, ZZZZZZZ).

After you've copied and pasted the text you want R to quote for you, place your cursor at the end of the "`quoted_string<-quote_strings()`" line you have in your editor and run it (e.g. press Ctrl+Enter).  Once you do that you will see the quoted string appear as a comment in your source editor window and the variable `quoted_string` will also contain the quoted string.

For example, I copy the following list in notepad:
AK, AL, AR, AS, AZ, CA, CO, CT, DC, DE, FL, GA, GU, HI, IA, ID, IL

Then, I run the line "`quoted_string<-quote_strings()`" and the following appears in my source editor and the string is also stored in quoted_string:

```
# "AK", "AL", "AR", "AS", "AZ", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DC", "DE", "FL", "GA", "GU", "HI", "IA", "ID", "IL"
```

I recommend [saving this user defined function in your .rprofile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37862352/how-to-make-a-function-available-at-start-up-in-r) so that the function will be available to you to use anytime you start up R.  That way, you don't have to redefine the function every time you want to use it after you shut down and restart R.  You can also modify this function if you like to take parameters such as whether you want a single quote or double quote and what character separates the words in your list.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you want this in order to make a vector, perhaps this function could be useful to you?

`getSplit = function(oneString, delim){
  return(unlist(strsplit(oneString, delim),use.names = F))
}`

## Example

`oneStringInst = "MI, ID, FL"
testResult = getSplit(oneStringInst, delim=", ")`