# Convert names as vector in R

Tags: r

I have more than 100 name-items on my R Script without " " and "," between them. I want to make a vector from them.

```
AWE XYA Name3 WERFS XYAGD ...... DSFSF
```

The vector should be

```
vec <- c("AWE", "XYA" ,"Name3" ,"WERFS" ,"XYAGD" ...... ,"DSFSF")
```

Instead of manually entering " " and ,. Is there a way to automate this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do that from Rstudio, you have some solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38047593/how-to-put-quotes-around-several-words-quickly-in-rstudio).

You also have a `Rstudio addin` to put quotation mark around words:

```r
remotes::install_github("hrbrmstr/hrbraddins")
```

See [there](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3184778/6-useful-r-functions-you-might-not-know.html) or [there](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3327573/do-more-with-r-rstudio-addins-and-keyboard-shortcuts.html). After putting quotation marks, you can do a find and replace after selecting the area in the script to transform `"` into `",`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file in which this is stored is called `temp.R`, you can use `scan` to get a character vector. This will also work if you have text (`.txt`) file.

```
vec <- scan('temp.R', what = "character", quiet = TRUE)
```