Is there a function to calculate a percentage of a number in R?
Let us say we want to calculate a certain percentage of a number, e.g. 50% of 80,000. We can of course write a quick calculation, e.g.:
> 80000 / 100 * 50
[1] 40000

Since I don't calculate percentages very often, I find that every time I have to calculate one I have to spend a couple of seconds reminding myself how to calculate it. And every time I have to calculate one I wonder if there isn't a quick function inbuilt into R that saves my lazy mind from having to do that mental gymnastics. So, is there? Something like:
percent(50, 80000)

I would also find code more comprehensible that way. My more verbally than mathematically inclined mind can immediately understand what percent(50, dat$foo) does, while there is one cognitive step more to do for me in dat$foo / 100 * 50.
I know I can define my own functions. That's not what I'm asking.

Note
If you think a percentage is too simple to calculate to deserve its own function, note that there are other very simple calculations built-in to Base R such as mean(x), which is no more complicated than sum(x) / length(x), so wouldn't really deserve it's own function, either.

Maybe you want to include your self defined function in your R profile. This way you will not have to define it in new projects. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37862352/how-to-make-a-function-available-at-start-up-in-r

Hm your percent() function is really percent_of(). percent(x), if it exists, should be implemented as x / 100: everything else would be wrong. Then you could implement perecent_of(p, x) as x * percent(p). (Or just skip that now-redundant part: surely percent_of(50, 80000) is no more readable than 80000 * percent(50)).

@Ben why is there no advantage to writing a function for a calculation you only do once? Surely the advantage is what you describe - that the code is more comprehensible?

FYI, mean is more than sum(x) / length(x).

@LulY Yeah, I thought about defining it in my .Rprofile but wanted to see if the function exixted somewhere, first.

"percent" literally means "per hundred". Why are any mental gymnastics needed to translate that into /100?

@Friede Thank you. (1) Do you mean x * 0.5 for x / 100 * 50? (I have a hard time understanding that markup.) (2) Yes. (3) I couldn't find anything in the scales package. (4) Could you give an example? (5) How is mean more than sum(x) / length(x)?

@Roland Because / 100 isn't the full calculation. To me "per hundred" doesn't translate to x / 100 * 50, but to x / 100 = y / 50 which I have to rearrange to find the calcuation I need to do. That's the "gymnastics".

@SamR True. (Plus some letters to satisfy minimum comment length requirements.)

"x percent of y" translates to "x / 100 * y". That should be extremely easy to remember.

@Roland Apparently I cannot remember it because I use it too rarely. That you think it should be easy to remember doesn't make it easy to remember for me. It's like that credit card PIN I only use once every foreign holiday versus the PIN for my cash card that I use twice every day and know better than my wife's birthday. If that calculation was the only thing I had to remember I'm sure I could, but my life is too full of things that are "easy to remember" to remember them all.

Yes, I understand. Still I would find it much easier to remember than the name of a function I use very rarely. But that might just be a consequence of different education.

The comments are getting a little much and this is a little long for one. I think this base R function does not exist. According to Meta, this is only an acceptable answer if it can be proven that this is the case. I'm not sure how to prove a negative. If you feel strongly, feel free to flag as Not An Answer.
I understand your issue and I don't think you need to justify or defend why something written out in words is easier to comprehend than the equivalent calculation, even if this is not the case for others. This is the whole basis of literate programming and avoiding magic numbers.
If you're going to define a function for this calculation, as several comments point out, it should not be called percent(). I would use an infix operator here:
`%of%` <- \(lhs, rhs) rhs * (lhs / 100)

I think it makes it clearest what is going on:
50 %of% 80000
# [1] 40000
10 %of% 200
# [1] 20
50 %of% c(2, 4, 6)
# [1] 1 2 3

It has been suggested you define a function which you can add to your .Rprofile. I, personally, would not. It means your code is not reproducible. I limit my .Rprofile to things like display options, such as how many rows to print. Instead, you could create a small, local package of utility functions. If this is how you like to write code it is likely that the list of functions will grow over time. I think this is how gtools started and I use it frequently (though you would not need to publish your package). This can be done in a few minutes these days with (the terribly named) usethis.

Great ideas, thank you! I consider calling the infix operator "percent_of" to make it even more telling: 50 %percent_of% 80000. I also like the idea to begin to create my own private package. I do have quite a few functions I use (ir-)regularly, so that might make sense.

@Friede lhs and rhs make more sense to me - but my brain reads %of% as "percent of", and apparently @Ben's does not - so I guess we're all different! Whether or not you store functions in your .Rprofile really depends on how you work with others - I've just been bitten once too many times when I've tried to run someone else's code and been hit with Error: could not find function ..., so I tend to be cautious.

"I don't think you need to justify or defend why something written out in words is easier to comprehend than the equivalent calculation, even if this is not the case for others" I love that sentence!! Often people question the question intead of answering it. I find that really annoying on SO but luckily there are also people giving answers. Great one!

@SamR gives a good answer using an infix operator.  If you tend to use pipes, infix operators aren't so convenient, so here's a suggestion for that case.
Your function needs two arguments, and pipes generally pipe one argument in to the function, and specify other arguments explicitly.  So you need to decide whether the percentage is likely to be piped in, or the value you want to compute a percentage of.  I'd guess it's the latter, e.g. you want to compute 50% of each of a vector of numbers more than you want to calculate a vector of percents of one (or more) numbers.
If my guess is correct, then you should specify the values first, and the percentage second, e.g.
percent <- function(value, percentage) {
  value*percentage/100
}

so that you can use it as
1:10 |> percent(10)

to get 10 percent of each value.
If you want to pipe percentages into the function, you can use the _ placeholder:
c(10, 20, 30) |> percent(x, percentage = _)

which would give 10%, 20% and 30% of a variable x.  (Here x should probably be a scalar or length 3.)

Fantastic! I suggest adding something like #| percent(value, percentage) to the function. That displays a function hint in the status bar of the R.app GUI. That way one doesn't have to remember how to use it ;-)
